# Comparing current record to previous record

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP & MySQL. I have Googled through few forums but don't know how to get this QUERY to work. Hopefully you guys can guide me.

**ITEMINFO**

```
--------------------------------------
| ItemNo | Description       | Price |
| AAAAA  | AAAAA description | $1.11 |
| BBBBB  | BBBBB description | $2.22 |
| CCCCC  | CCCCC description | $3.33 |
```

**STOREINFO**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| StoreNo | Add1        | Add2 | City     | State | Zip   |
| 11111   | 111 Main St | # 1  | New York | NY    | 10001 |
| 22222   | 222 Main St | # 2  | New York | NY    | 10001 |
| 33333   | 333 Main St | # 3  | New York | NY    | 10001 |
| 44444   | 444 Main St | # 4  | New York | NY    | 10001 |
```

**STOREORDER**

```
-------------------------------
| StoreNo | Quantity | ItemNo |
| 11111   | 10       | AAAAA  |
| 11111   | 5        | BBBBB  |
| 33333   | 50       | BBBBB  |
| 22222   | 20       | AAAAA  |
```

**QUERY:** List all Stores which has ordered; and which item & qty is ordered?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM STOREINFO ".
    "LEFT JOIN STOREORDER ON STOREINFO.StoreNo = STOREORDER.StoreNo ".
    "LEFT JOIN ITEMINFO ON STOREORDER.ItemNo = ITEMINFO.ItemNo ".
    "ORDER BY STOREINFO.StoreNo ASC";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out the contents of each row into a table 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$CheckStoreNo = trim($row['StoreNo']);
if($CheckStoreNo != "") 
        {
        echo " *print store info* ";
---->>>>    echo " *list ALL item ordered & qty* ";
        }
}
    echo "<hr>";
?>
```

**OUTPUT:** (formatted)

```
Company: Store # 11111
111 Main St, # 1, New York, NY 10001
Tel: 111-111-1111
This store ordered - Item: AAAAA - 10 pc(s)

Company: Store # 11111
111 Main St, # 1, New York, NY 10001
Tel: 111-111-1111
This store ordered - Item: BBBBB - 5 pc(s)

Company: Store # 22222
222 Main St, # 2, New York, NY 10001
Tel:  222-222-2222
This store ordered - Item: AAAAA - 20 pc(s)

Company: Store # 33333
333 Main St, # 3, New York, NY 10001
Tel:  333-333-3333
This store ordered - Item: BBBBB - 50 pc(s)
```

I managed to get this far. Now if you notice store #11111 actually have 2(two) orders of different items. Instead of ECHO all the duplicate company info, I just need the SAME company info ECHO once and list ALL the items ordered for Store# 11111.

**EXAMPLE: This is What I Need!**

```
Company: Store # 11111
111 Main St, # 1, New York, NY 10001
Tel: 111-111-1111
1) Item: AAAAA - 10 pc(s)
2) Item: BBBBB - 5 pc(s)

Company: Store # 22222
... And so on ...
```

I got all orders list out based on each store's order. (Thanks to @cularis).

Now, How can I close/end it after each store's order?

**Example: Close each store's order for *Printing* purpose!**

```
Company: Store # 11111
111 Main St, # 1, New York, NY 10001
Tel: 111-111-1111
1) Item: AAAAA - 10 pc(s)
2) Item: BBBBB - 5 pc(s)
------- End of order for Store # 11111 -----

Company: Store # 22222
... List order ...
------- End of order for Store # 22222 -----
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no MySQL, but a PHP question.

You have to do this in your frontend like this:

```
// Print out the contents of each row into a table 
$OldStoreNo = ""
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$CheckStoreNo = trim($row['StoreNo']);
if($CheckStoreNo != "") {
    if($OldStoreNo != $CheckStoreNo) {
        echo " *print store info* ";
        $OldStoreNo = $CheckStoreNo;
    }
    echo " *list item ordered & qty* ";
  }
}
```

Along with the OldStoreNo, you can keep track of the current item count per store to output a number next to each item.

Comment: Everything work great! Thank you. =D

Next Question: How can I close it after listing all the items for each store (for Printing purpose to each individual store)?

Comment: Before printing shop information for the next shop, print everything you want to come AFTER the last shop. You have to check if its the first store with a boolean, because then you don't want to print the shop end info.

Comment: if($CurrentStoneNo != $CheckStoreNo and $numcount > 0) { PRINT-END-ORDER }

Comment: I insert the IF Statement after "$CheckStoreNo = trim($row['StoreNo']);". I don't this is the correct way to do it (It can't close the "Last ORDER". Please advise. =(

Comment: You have to print the store-info one last time after the end of your while loop.

Comment: I would refactor the "print store endinfo" and "print store start info" into seperate functions and call them, less clutter.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that myself too. Will post my final work if is working. Thank you so much for your help =D

Answer (score 0):

keep track of the store number in the while loop
if it is the same as the previous, print the order, else print the storeinfo and the order

```
//track store_no
$current_store_no = false;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if (trim($row['StoreNo']) != $current_store_no) {
        //print store info
        $current_store_no = trim($row['StoreNo'])
    }
    //print order info
}
```